# How to get next page from currently fetched page using facebook4j

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

What I am trying to do is fetch next page contents on button press, but when initializing first page i can fetch easily 2nd page. This is the place i am stuck. How do I get third page from second page?

```
ResponseList<Post> feeds = facebook.getFeed("PAGE_ID", new Reading().limit(200));
    ArrayList<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();
    if(Next == 1) {
        Paging<Post> paging = feeds.getPaging();
        ResponseList<Post> page2 = facebook.fetchNext(paging);
        for (int i = 0; i < page2.size(); i++) {
            Post post = page2.get(i);
            items.add(new Items(post.getFrom().getName(), post.getMessage()));
        }
    }else if(Next == 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < feeds.size(); i++) {
            Post post = feeds.get(i);
            items.add(new Items(post.getFrom().getName(), post.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

i am using Next variable as function parameter to be sure initialize app from "feeds" then "page2" for everything else. (load next page button press etc.)